# Using custom contentType to display Visualforce page data in an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, excel

According to the Visualforce Developer Guide, you can specify a different format for a Visualforce page by using the ContentType attribute on the  tag. Specifically you can display Visualforce page data in a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet, specifying a value of: application/vnd.ms-excel.

I am following this example here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_content_type.htm

This works great in desktop, but does not seem to work in Salesforce1, specifically I get an error message when opening that page in mobile that states, "Unable to Read Document". I could not find any documentation as to whether this truly is unsupported for Salesforce1. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have reader software in your mobile that opens/reads document that is downloaded. Ex, Google Docs.